# Can't find Exposure Time or ISO data from .DNG file but Windows can

Tags: python, image-processing, metadata

I have been trying a few methods to automatically read the meta-data files from a vast library of pictures I need to process and balance. I want to be able to just pull the Exposure time and ISO in order to do this. However, the Exif methods result in no listing for exposure time or ISO even when I call the specific bit address it is empty.

However, when I pull up the properties in Windows, I see the exposure time and ISO. I tried to use an IPTC data grabber, but that didn't work because the pictures were in the.DNG file type.

Does anyone know of a library that I could use & some code to extract this data?

Comment: Sometimes relevant EXIF data is stored in proprietary tags.  In the case of a popular format like DNG those tags will be widely known.

Comment: Is there a list of those proprietary tags anywhere? When I did a quick search for the hardware I'm using it results lost of product pages and not specific EXIF tags

Comment: https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html looks like an interesting reference.  Turned it up with a quick Google search.

Comment: Yeah, I used those tags and the data was still null in Python. However, the data is found and pulled by Windows

Comment: Mentioning the camera model might help.

Comment: Sharing one of your DNGs might help. Try using Google Drive or Dropbox, for example.